# Emulator doesn't start in eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've tried to find answers and similar problems, but nothing has fixed the problem.

I created a project and wanted to run the emulator to check if everything is working fine. But the emulator doesn't start up. It gives the following ouput, in console:

```
[2015-01-08 10:20:06 - MTNInfoHub] ------------------------------  
[2015-01-08 10:20:06 - MTNInfoHub] Android Launch!  
[2015-01-08 10:20:06 - MTNInfoHub] adb is running normally.  
[2015-01-08 10:20:06 - MTNInfoHub] Performing com.mtninfohub.MainHub activity launch  
[2015-01-08 10:20:33 - MTNInfoHub] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'test'    
[2015-01-08 10:20:33 - Emulator] ko:Could not create temp file for system partition image: %s,size=0x%llx  
[2015-01-08 10:20:33 - Emulator]
```

Please help me.
Running on centos, 32 bit architecture

Comment: what operating system do you use ?

Comment: centos is linux-based. Check if the user that executed eclipse, have the permission to write the temp folder

Comment: thanks for reply, I did checked, for the android-sdk folder the user has the needed permission. but not sure if thats where the temp file is created? Haven't found anything online saying where its created, yet.

Comment: the directory used is `/temp` or `/tmp`

Comment: I found the directory where the temp file is created. /tmp/android. Changed its permissions and the emulator worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem with Android Studio. To fix it, I just ran Android Studio as administrator.